# Parity warp sync doesn't return event logs

Tags: parity, events, warp-sync

Our Dapp uses events as a form of storage. For connection to blockchain we use local Parity node.

A couple of days ago I needed to resync it after the server failure. After the resync all methods that use web3's getPastEvents (which uses eth_getLogs, I believe) return an empty array.

It seems that warp sync doesn't download event logs at all. If I make event-emitting transaction after the sync, getPastEvents returns this new event, so it increases my confidence in the fact that warp sync is the source of the problem. Besides when connected to Infura node methods return proper event logs.

Is there a way to download only event logs after warp sync? Or is it possible to warpsync only to specific block and then switch to full sync?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, in now the `openethereum`, you have an option called:

```
    --warp-barrier=[NUM]
        When warp enabled never attempt regular sync before warping to block
        NUM.
```

Give it a go.